# Can script be configured to "exit on unhandled exception"?

Tags: matlab

Is there a simple way to configure a MATLAB script so that it exits upon encountering an unhandled exception (as opposed to reverting to the REPL)?

The reason for this is that when executing many runs of a script in (unsupervised) batch mode, any script that fails should exit immediately, and not hang indifinitely at (unattended) interactive prompt.

IMPORTANT CLARIFICATION: this script is meant to be executed from the Unix command line, not from the MATLAB interactive prompt.  More specifically, the script is to be invoked with

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -r myscript.m
```

The script should *always* terminate MATLAB after it has executed all its code, and return a status code reflecting its success (0) or failure (some non-zero integer).

---

I'm looking for a global setting (or a command-line flag) that can be put into effect without affecting the rest of the code.

IOW, I'm looking for something analogous to the `-e` flag available in some Unix shells (e.g. bash, zsh), which has the effect of aborting a script immediately whenever the return status of a statement is non-zero (meaning that the statement failed).

---

I know that I can wrap the entire body of a script with a `try-catch`, like this (for example):

```
try
    exit_code = 0;

    %
    % BODY OF SCRIPT
    %

catch exc
    fprintf(2, 'CAUGHT EXCEPTION:\n');
    fprintf(2, '%s(%d): %s\n', exc.stack.file, exc.stack.line, exc.message);
    exit_code = 1;
end

exit(exit_code);
```

...but, as I said above, I'm looking for something simple, with no, or at most minimal, impact on the code.

Comment: A `try`/`catch` pair is the only way to do this. Note that `exit` exits MATLAB completely. You *could* put the script elsewhere and call it by name where you have "BODY OF SCRIPT" rather than modifying the script itself. Also you shouldn't be getting an interactive prompt on an error unless you have `dbstop if error` enabled. You can disable that with `dbclear`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior when an unhandled exception occurs is that information about the error will be printed to the command window and control will return to the command window. You should not be getting an interactive prompt from the error unless you've explicitly enabled it with `dbstop if error` or there is a `try`/`catch` with a `keyboard` command in the `catch` block. To just get a plain error rather than an interactive prompt you can use [`dbclear if error`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html#buzewwc-1) to disable this behavior. I would check your startup files to make sure that you don't have `dbstop if error` in there.

A `try`/`catch` pair is really the only way that this can be done. What you can do is wrap your calls to your script with another file and put the call to your script within a `try`/`catch` block. This has the added benefit that you don't have to modify the script itself, just the "runner".

Also you won't want to use `exit` as that completely exits MATLAB.

**`your_script.m`**

```
disp('Doing my thing')
error('Throwing an error!')
```

**`calling_script.m`**

```
for k = 1:100
    try
        % Call your other script and hope for no errors!
        your_script
    catch ME
        % Print information about the error and continue
        fprintf(2, 'CAUGHT EXCEPTION:\n');
        fprintf(2, '%s(%d): %s\n', ME.stack.file, ME.stack.line, ME.message);
    end
end
```

**Update**

Based upon the clarification that you've provided that you want to run this from the Unix command line, you'll still want to use something similar with a `try`/`catch` statement combined with `exit`. Again, you could do this in an external file as shown above

**`calling_script.m`**

```
code = 0;

try
    your_script
catch ME
    fprintf(2, 'CAUGHT EXCEPTION:\n');
    fprintf(2, '%s(%d): %s\n', ME.stack.file, ME.stack.line, ME.message);
    code = 1;
end

exit(code)
```

Comment: Thanks.  After reading your answer I realized that my question needed to include an important clarification; I've just added it.  In brief: the script is meant to be invoked always from the Unix command line, not from MATLAB's command window.

Comment: @kjo You still have to do something similar. I've shown an alternative to your solution above in the update.